# Using FaceBook Sdk in my Unity Game (Login and User's FB_id)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, 2d-games, facebook-unity-sdk

I've been working with integration of Facebook sdk in my unity game. In the first page I kept a fb login option and I'm trying to fetch the player's fb_id(with which I will be making an online leaderboard). I'am facing two problems.They are:

1. Only my apps developers, test-users and owner(me) can login only first time. If i clear my apps data I face a hash key validation problem. There will be a screenshot below.
2. I need the fb_ids of all users . But I am getting only the fb_ids of people who has roles (owner, developer and test users)  . How can I get the fb_ids of all users?

NB: My game is published in google play and reviewed by Facebook with necessary permissions. 
Google Play Link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.BLI.CatchTheBaby&hl=en

[image: I face this hashkey error problem though i used the right haskey from my unity's facebook settings]

Answer (score 0):

Facebook SDK does not allow you to get data of all users.
Their API returns only your friends ids,name etc. Here is an online tester of Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

If you want to get all users FB IDs you have to store them on your online database like this: When user is doing his first login to Facebook from your app, you are sending returned id to database by some kind of webrequest. Then you can fetch data with all users IDs.

Comment: Did you add and configure your game into facebook developer panel? You need to set the right package name and keyhash, which you can get from unity>Facebook>Edit Settings.